# Remove the sequence of at least N consecutive values in a vector

Tags: r, optimization, vector

Here is my problem. I have a large vector of positive data. My goal is to remove the sequences of at least N consecutive values ​​that are repeated in the vector (all of repeated values must be strictly > 0).

I've written a program that works and is as follows : 
X is my vector of numeric values ;
N is the minimum length of repeated sequences.

```
rmpParNASerieRepetee <- function(X, N)
{
    X_ <- paste("T", paste(X, collapse="T"), "T", sep="")
    ind.parcours <- 1
    ind.sup <- c()

    # Loop on the values
    while ( ind.parcours <= (length(X)-N+1) )
    {
        # indices of my sequence of N values
        deb <- ind.parcours
        fin <- ind.parcours + N-1

        # sequence of N values to search in the vector
        serie  <- X[deb:fin]
        serie_ <- paste("T", paste(serie, collapse="T"), "T", sep="")


        borne <- 1*(ind.parcours < (length(X)-N+1)) + 0*(ind.parcours == (length(X)-N+1))
        if (sum(X[(length(X)-N+1):length(X)]==serie)==3) borne <- 0

        # split my string vector by my sequence vector of N values and count the pieces of result
        if ( length(unlist(strsplit(X_, serie_)))-1 > borne && length(which(serie!=0))>=N)
        { ind.sup <- unique(c(ind.sup, deb:fin)) }
        ind.parcours <- ind.parcours+1
    }
    if (length(ind.sup !=0)) { X[ind.sup] <- NA }

    list_return <- list(X=X, Ind.sup=unique(sort(ind.sup)))
    return (list_return)
}
```

I think my function is really not optimal (calculation time of 1:15 for a vector of 92,000 values, N=18). And I have to do this step 1600 times... It would take around 3 months...

Does anyone have a better idea ?

Example :

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,0,4,1,2,3,8,9,1,2,3,4,0)
N <- 3
# (1,2,3) is a sequence of 3 elements which is repeated
# (1,2,3,4) is  sequence of 4 elements which is repeated
# no other sequence of length at least 3 repeats
# my result should also be :
# NA NA NA NA 0 4 NA NA NA 8 9 NA NA NA NA 0
# The result of my program is :
# $X
# [1] NA NA NA NA  0  4 NA NA NA  8  9 NA NA NA NA  0
#$Ind.sup
# [1]  1  2  3  4  7  8  9 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: Why don't you describe what you're trying to do, it will be much more useful than putting your code.

Comment: Your data looks like integers. If that's the case, storing it as-is (`integer` and not `numeric`) could make the suggested answers faster.

Comment: Question: How large can the individual elements be? Are they all in (0,9)?

Comment: No, I don't know the values. It can be 2 as 1256.

Comment: I add an exemple, can you see my new edit ? Thanks

Comment: Any solution ? Nobody ?

Comment: @sandikou Are the numbers in the sequence `x` always exactly one digit? Could you, for example, have `c(1,15,1,0,1,15,1)`?

Comment: Yes it can be any number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have optimized my function, and now it takes "only" 10 minutes for a vector of length 92000.
Maybe someone could find an other solution more faster than mine.

Imagine my vector is `X<-c(1,2,3,4,0,7,8,1,2,3,NA,8,9,1,2,3,4)` and `N=3`.
`c(1,2,3)` et `c(1,2,3,4)` are the only repeated sequences of length at least N without NA or 0. So my result should be `NA NA NA NA 0 7 8 NA NA NA NA 8 9 NA NA NA NA`.

To answer my problem, I use this principle :

I create a big string like this : `X_ <- T1T2T3T4T0T7T8T1T2T3TNAT8T9T1T2T3T4` in which, all `X` values are concatened by `T`. For each little string of length `N=3` (ex : the first is `T1T2T3T`), I break my big string `X_` using `strsplit` function with the pattern "little string". If the length of the result is more than 2, the sequence is repeated.
Care must be taken not to take null values ​​in the series, and some adaptation must be done to avoid edge phenomena (`borne` in my function)...

I created these functions which work :

```
# Function to count NA in a vector
count.na <- function(vec) { return (length(which(is.na(vec)))) }

# Function to detect sequence of stricly postive numbers of length at least N
rmpParNASerieRepetee <- function(X, N, val.min=0)
{
    # Collapse the vector to make a big string
    X_ <- paste("T", paste(X, collapse="T"), "T", sep="")

    # Index term
    ind.parcours <- 1
    ind.sup <- c()

    # Loop on X values
    while ( ind.parcours <= (length(X)-N+1) )
    {
         # Selection of the sequence to be detected
         deb <- ind.parcours
         fin <- ind.parcours + N-1
         serie <- X[deb:fin]

            # All values are > 0
            if ( length(which(serie>0)) >= (N-count.na(serie)) )
            {
                    # Research of repetition with strsplit
                    serie_ <- paste("T", paste(serie, collapse="T"), "T", sep="")
                    borne <- 1*(ind.parcours < (length(X)-N+1)) + 0*(ind.parcours == (length(X)-N+1)) 
                    if (sum(X[(length(X)-N+1):length(X)]==serie, na.rm=TRUE)==N) borne <- 0

                    if (length(unlist(strsplit(X_, serie_)))-1 > borne) 
                         ind.sup <- unique( c(ind.sup, deb:fin) )

                    # Incrementation
                    ind.parcours <- ind.parcours + 1
             }
            # Contains 0
            else
            {   ind.parcours <- ind.parcours + max(which(serie==0))
            }
    }

    # Invalidaion of repeated sequences
    if (length(ind.sup !=0)) { X[ind.sup] <- NA }

    # Return
    list_return <- list(X=X, Ind.sup=unique(sort(ind.sup)))
    return (list_return)

 }
```

I hope someone will find an other way to solve my problem !

Answer (score 1):

Try using `table` and `%in%` to get faster speed due to vectorisation.

```
rmpParNASerieRepetee<-function(X,N){
  tab<-table(X[X>0])
  over.n<-as.numeric(names(tab)[tab>=N])
  ind<-X %in% over.n
  Ind.sup<-which(ind)
  X<-ifelse(ind,NA,X)
  list(Ind.sup,X)
}

X <- c(1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,1,4,1,2,3,4,8,9,1,2,3,1,4,1,0,0,0)
rmpParNASerieRepetee(X,3)
# [[1]]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  9 10 11 12 13 14 17 18 19 20 21 22
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] NA NA NA NA  0  0  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA  8  9 NA NA NA NA NA NA  0  0  0
```

And a little test for 92000 values:

```
X<-sample(1:10000,92000,TRUE)
system.time(rmpParNASerieRepetee(X,3))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.14    0.00    0.14
```

Comment: +1, but you really ought to put some space in your code. Things like `ind<-X` can be confusing (an assignment or a comparison?)

Comment: Perhaps using `over.n <- which(tab>=N)` and `X[Ind.sup] <- NA` would be even faster?

Comment: my sequences are composed of N consecutive values

Comment: Interesting fact: let `x <- sample(as.integer(1:100), 1e7, TRUE)` then compare `system.time(rle(sort(x)))` to `system.time(table(x))`. The former is faster. I was expecting the opposite... If the OP's data allows for it, `tabulate` will be a lot faster.

Comment: @sandikou Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I think. My misunderstanding coincidentally had the same output, leading me to believe that I understood correctly.

Comment: I think this just counts the number of times an entry appears (how many 1's, 2's, etc.) and tags if an entry appears more than N times. Gives different answer than OP's code with  `x <- c(1,2,3,8,0,8,0,8,0,8,0,8,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3)`

Comment: @jlhoward Indeed, you are correct. This is due to my misunderstanding, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

A way:

```
f <- function(X, N)
{
 .rle <- rle(sort(X))
 res <- .rle$values[.rle$lengths >= N]
 res <- res[res > 0]
 inds <- X %in% res
 X[inds] <- NA 
 list(X = X, Ind = which(inds)) 
}

#> f(X, 3)
#$X
# [1] NA NA NA NA  0  0  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA  8  9 NA NA NA NA NA NA  0  0  0
#
#$Ind
# [1]  1  2  3  4  9 10 11 12 13 14 17 18 19 20 21 22
```

Comment: my sequences are composed of N consecutive values

Comment: @sandikou, they are returning the same output as you show in your question. So if this is not what you are looking for, you need to be a little more clear and edit your question.

Comment: That's not enough. Please provide an example where your definition of *consecutive* becomes relevant. Again, the answers here are giving the same output as yours...

Comment: @sandikou: Could you add an example where the output between your function and the ones posted here differ? I, honestly, can't get it.

Comment: This also gives a result different than OP's code with `x <- c(1,2,3,8,0,8,0,8,0,8,0,8,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3)`

Comment: And just to answer your question, the result with `x <- c(1,2,3,8,0,8,0,8,0,8,0,8,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3)` is `#$X
 [1] NA NA NA  8  0  8  0  8  0  8  0  8  0 NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA`
`#$Ind.sup
[1]  1  2  3 14 15 16 18 19 20`

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about this is that in a sequence, each element differs from the last one by 1, so:

```
X    <- c(1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,1,4,1,2,3,4,8,9,1,2,3,1,4,1,0,0,0)
y    <- X[-1]
diff <- y-X[1:length(X)-1]
diff
[1]  1  1  1 -4  0  0  0  1  3 -3  1  1  1  4  1 -8  1  1 -2  3 -3 -1  0  0
```

And now you're looking for sequences of > N 1's in `diff`.

Comment: my repeted sequence could be `c(1,4,1)` and in this case, the `diff` function doesn't help me

Comment: my sequences are composed of N consecutive values

Comment: `c(1,4,1,4,1,4,1,4,1,4,1,4)` is NOT 'consecutive' by most people's interpretation of that word. It is a repeating sequence with a cycle length of 2.